# Quickly find indices that have values larger than a threshold in Numpy/PyTorch

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

**Task**

Given a numpy or pytorch matrix, find the indices of cells that have values that are larger than a given threshold.

**My implementation**

```
#abs_cosine is the matrix
#sim_vec is the wanted

sim_vec = []
for m in range(abs_cosine.shape[0]):
    for n in range(abs_cosine.shape[1]):
        # exclude diagonal cells
        if m != n and abs_cosine[m][n] >= threshold:
            sim_vec.append((m, n))
```

**Concerns**

**Speed**. All other computations are built on Pytorch, using `numpy` is already a compromise, because it has moved computations from GPU to CPU. Pure python `for` loops will make the whole process even worse (for small data set already 5 times slower). **I was wondering if we can move the whole computation to Numpy (or pytorch) without invoking any `for` loops?**

An improvement I can think of (but got stuck...)

> bool_cosine = abs_cosine > threshold

which returns a boolean matrix of `True` and `False`. But I cannot find a way to quick retrieve the indices of the `True` cells.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following is for PyTorch (fully on GPU)

```
# abs_cosine should be a Tensor of shape (m, m)
mask = torch.ones(abs_cosine.size()[0])
mask = 1 - mask.diag()
sim_vec = torch.nonzero((abs_cosine >= threshold)*mask)

# sim_vec is a tensor of shape (?, 2) where the first column is the row index and second is the column index
```

The following works in numpy

```
mask = 1 - np.diag(np.ones(abs_cosine.shape[0]))
sim_vec = np.nonzero((abs_cosine >= 0.2)*mask)
# sim_vec is a 2-array tuple where the first array is the row index and the second array is column index
```

Comment: In fact, the PyTorch approach works for ND tensors of arbitrary shape if you initialize `mask = torch.ones(img.size())` instead of cherry picking the first size axis

Comment: The `mask = 1 - mask.diag()` addition is only needed if your intention is for `sim_vec` to exclude diagonal elements from the returned indices (per the OP request). However, it can easily be omitted to allow all indices as valid, or modified to exclude some non-diagonal subset of indices

Comment: I'm not sure if this is actually all on cuda. The docs for `torch.nonzero` say "When input is on CUDA, torch.nonzero() causes host-device synchronization."

Answer (score 0):

**This is about twice as fast than np.where**

```
import numba as nb
@nb.njit(fastmath=True)

def get_threshold(abs_cosine,threshold):
  idx=0
  sim_vec=np.empty((abs_cosine.shape[0]*abs_cosine.shape[1],2),dtype=np.uint32)
  for m in range(abs_cosine.shape[0]):
    for n in range(abs_cosine.shape[1]):
      # exclude diagonal cells
      if m != n and abs_cosine[m,n] >= threshold:
        sim_vec[idx,0]=m
        sim_vec[idx,1]=n
        idx+=1

  return sim_vec[0:idx,:]
```

The first call takes about 0.2s longer (compilation overhead). If the array is on the GPU, there may be also a way to do the whole computation on the GPU.

Nevertheless I am not really satisfied with the performance, since a simple boolean operation is about 5 times faster than the solution shown above and 10 times faster than np.where. If the order of the indices doesn't matter this problem can also be parallelized.

Comment: The order doesn't matter.